# How to implement Google Analytics V3 on multiple Activities?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've implemented Google Analytics V3 for an Android app exactly as instructed here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/

For step 2, I've added the `activityStart` and `activityStop` methods to a base activity which every activity extends from. However, looking at the real time dashboard, only one specific activity seems to be logged.

Why aren't the other ones being logged? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to build a test app and see what I could come up with for you. My test app consists of 3 total activities: `Splash`, `Main Activity`, and `Secondary Activity`.

`Splash` is set as the launcher & and main in the manifest, other 2 activities have no intent filters.

Just to ensure that this didn't necessarily hinge upon user activity but rather kicked off per activity creation, Splash creates a runnable that lasts 4 seconds before loading the first activity and finishing:

```
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));
```

The first activity loads and is just a blank screen with a button. On click, an intent is created for the secondary activity.

All three of these classes extend the `TrackedActivity` class, which uses Google's sample code.

**Sure enough, I was seeing nothing in the real-time dashboard except** `com.test.testproject.SecondaryActivity`.

**Neither `splash` nor `main` were showing up.**

Next step, turn on verbose logging in your analytics.xml file:

```
<!-- Enable Verbose Logging -->
  <string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>
```

I did that and took a look at the log output, and was stumped to see that all 3 of my activities appeared to be logging correctly.

> 10-06 16:47:56.194: V/GAV3(7704): GET
>   /collect?v=1&ul=en-us&t=appview&ht=1381092218141&sr=720x1280&an=TestProject&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx&aid=com.test.testproject&cid=f0a09e69-67e8-4ac0-b4b7-748be827efa7&av=1.0&_u=.r8&_v=ma3.0.0&cd=com.test.testproject.MainActivity&qt=258067&z=25
>   HTTP/1.1
>
> 10-06 16:47:56.234: V/GAV3(7704): GET
>   /collect?v=1&ul=en-us&t=appview&ht=1381092220248&sr=720x1280&an=TestProject&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx&aid=com.test.testproject&cid=f0a09e69-67e8-4ac0-b4b7-748be827efa7&av=1.0&_u=.98&_v=ma3.0.0&cd=com.test.testproject.SecondaryActivity&qt=255994&z=26
>   HTTP/1.1

Of note, the hit stores were out of order:

> 10-06 16:51:05.008: V/GAV3(7704): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit
>   to store  PATH: https:  PARAMS: v=1,  ul=en-us,  t=appview, 
>   ht=1381092665018,  sr=720x1280,  an=TestProject,  tid=UA-xxxxxxx, 
>   aid=com.test.testproject,  cid=f0a09e69-67e8-4ac0-b4b7-748be827efa7, 
>   av=1.0,  _u=.r98,  cd=com.test.testproject.SecondaryActivity,
>
> 10-06 16:51:06.970: V/GAV3(7704): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit
>   to store  PATH: https:  PARAMS: v=1,  ul=en-us,  t=appview, 
>   ht=1381092666979,  sr=720x1280,  an=TestProject,  tid=UA-xxxxxxx, 
>   aid=com.test.testproject,  cid=f0a09e69-67e8-4ac0-b4b7-748be827efa7, 
>   av=1.0,  _u=.98,  cd=com.test.testproject.MainActivity,

Checking the real-time dashboard I continued to only see one activity, like so:
[image: Checking the real-time dashboard I continued to only see one activity...]

And then I noticed in the top right corner it had defaulted to filtering my resultset to only the 2nd activity!

Clearing the filter then showed me all three activities, like so:
[image: All 3 activities shown in real-time]

Stupid as it might be, ensure that google's dashboard is defaulting the filtering for you, I barely noticed it in the first place.

And if that doesn't help, post up a code sample so I can take a look at what's going on. If you want, I'm happy to bundle up this sample app so you can drop in your UA ID and try it out yourself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't believe that was the problem, I feel so stupid for not looking at the screen properly...

Comment: Don't feel stupid, it's really easy to miss! I sat there scratching my head for 20 minutes until I noticed it.